# Rewrite rule with redirect in php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I seem to have problem with an .htaccess rewriterule.

What I want to do is a dispatcher of this form:

```
[website]/[parameter1-text]/[parameter2-text]
```

I have in my .htaccess the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ dispatcher.php?s1=$1&s2=$2
```

So far so good. But s1 and s2 are some variables that need to be matched in a database (mysql) and return the true variables that feed the script view.php in the following format:

```
view.php?category=[s1]&subcategory=[s2]&objects=5
```

How can I redirect this properly using header("Location: /view.php[...]"); and having the url unchanged (for example: http://example.com/CARS/BLUE http://example.com/SLIPPERS/RED/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all fix some minor issues with your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ dispatcher.php?s1=$1&s2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Now inside `dispatcher.php` do your Mysql stuff and fetch values of `s1` and `s2` from database. Once you're done and want to internally forward your request to: `view.php?category=[s1]&subcategory=[s2]&objects=5` have this type of PHP code:

```
$_GET['category'] = $value-of-s1-from-DB;
$_REQUEST['category'] = $_GET['category'];
$_GET['subcategory'] = $value-of-s2-from-DB;
$_REQUEST['subcategory'] = $_GET['subcategory'];
$_GET['objects'] = '5';
$_REQUEST['objects'] = $_GET['objects'];
// now include view.php
// all your parameters are available in view.php in $_GET array
require_once("view.php");
```